# React rendering delay

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming from Angluar world, where change detection is way more aggressive than in React. I'm heaving issue with rendering component that asynchronously receives image URLs. Below is sinppet:

```
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.els = this.props.imagesUrls.map(url => {
            return (
                <img src={url}></img>
                )
        })
        console.log(this.els)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="image-list">
                IMAGE LIST
                {this.props.imagesUrls.map(el => <img src={el}></img>)} // Method 1
                {this.els} //Method 2
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Method 1 works like charm, method  2 is delayed (i.e. component must recieve second time props to render provious props urls.

I assume this is simple issue related with asynchronosity, but I will appriciate any help and/or leadning material to help me avoid sucj pitfals.

Comment: first one is not . right way to render ,You should use setsState.second one is right approach

Comment: props.imagesUrls are provided by parent component after some fetch of URLs. It happens as onClick event handler. In case of method 2, first click does nothing. Second click refresh component with fetched data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second method, two things cause the delay,

**First:** `componentDidUpdate` is called after render(not called on the first time render) and hence the call is executed after the component is rendered

**Second:** You are setting the returned data to a class variable which doesn't cause a re-render, any other change which causes a re-render will only result in the data being displayed. You must use `setState` instead.

However, the first method is the right way to handle such a render

Comment: When I'm using `componentWillUpdate` the effect is the same, but I see your second point!

Comment: Yes, Also don't use componentWillUpdate/componentDidUpdate to setState  without a conditional check or else your App will get stuck in a loop

Comment: What kind of conditional check you  mean exactly?

Comment: @Tomas, a check like comparing prevProps and currentProps to check if they Change and then only setState basically some check which won't always be returning true,